# Get number of lines in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

A lot of the old solutions to this same question are deprecated (UILineWordWrap, to name one deprecated one). I also found some of them unreliable. So, in IOS 8, how should I find the number of lines in a uilabel?

Answer (score 6):

As of **iOS8**, you can use `[NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes]` to get the height of a given string.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: label.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy};
NSInteger options = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;

CGRect rect = [self boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:options attributes:attributes context:nil];
NSInteger numberOfLines = floor(ceilf(rect.size.height) / label.font.lineHeight);
```

As an alternative approach; you can also make use of `[UILabel: sizeToFit]` method as follows if you already set the width of your label:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[label sizeToFit];
NSInteger numberOfLines = floor(ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(label.frame)) / label.font.lineHeight);
```

Comment: undefined variable width?

Comment: @user4807387 `width` is the width of label because width of the label must be known for both of them to work.

Comment: how to acces that? label.width isn't valid

Comment: I'm assuming you mean label.bounds.size.width, but am really not sure

Comment: I will upvote your question if you give me an answer and explanation to my question about width.

Comment: @user4807387 `width` is the maximum width that label can take, probably the width of its superview.