# How can I hide a label if another label is taking up X number of lines?

Tags: swift, uilabel

Say I have two labels, one on top of the other. `Label 1` is set to have a maximum number of lines of 2 (`numberOfLines=2`). So sometimes, depending on the text, `Label 1` can take up TWO lines. The thing though is that a maximum of 2 lines should be shown between both labels, where `Label 1`'s second line takes precedence over `Label 2`. (Also, `Label 2` is always 1 line.)

So either of these 2 scenarios are possible:

```
Label 1 text
Label 2 text
```

OR

```
Label 1 text (line 1)
Label 1 text (line 2)
```

The only way I thought to attack this was to simply hide `Label 2` if `Label 1` is taking up 2 lines. But the problem is, how can I determine how many lines `Label 1` is taking up?

I've found a few other answers about this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108745/how-to-find-actual-number-of-lines-of-uilabel), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787965/get-number-of-lines-in-uilabel)), but none seem to work for me. Is there perhaps a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should just use one label, and construct the text seperately by the code and pass the final text into the label. In order to have a new line, you can use "\n". If you want to have a different fonts/color etc, you can always use AttributedString. This will be much cleaner, easier to change, and more flexible to maintain in the future.

Comment: this is a great answer thanks. i do however seem to have one issue with this approach. if the first part of the text (formerly known as `Label 1`) takes up 2 lines, i don't want to see the ellipsis ("...") showing (since the new line character and text of what was known as `Label 2` is now part of the same label), because i still consider them 2 different pieces of text. i WOULD want the "..." to show if the first part was say 3 lines and was being truncated to 2. is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging. What I understood that you want to have elipsis on the second line only if the text overflows and not on the first line, I think you can easily achieve this if you keep the number of line upto 2, and the rest will be exactly what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you working with Constraint? or Did you have knowledge about `NSLayoutConstraints`?

you can easily do that with managing proper constraint and it doesn't matter how many line will text have you can show both label with text.

make sure `label.numberofline = 0`. // It will take line as text.